# reading svg file, modify and put into an Image

Tags: image, svg

I am loading a svg file into an image like this:

```
let img = new Image;
img.onload = function () {
    // some stuff
}
img.src = "circle.svg";
```

but would like to replace some bit of the svg file before loading it into the image, for instance:

```
let svg = await fetch("circle.svg")
   .then(res => {
       return res.text();
   });
svg = svg.replace("red", "green");
```

How to load this into an image ?